# Excluding levels in a categorical predictor in logistic regression

Tags: categorical-data, binary-data

I am doing a binary logistic regression with one explanatory variable. I got 7 treatments originally in this variable, but what I am actually interested in is testing the difference between two of these treatments. If I reduce number of treatments in my test, do I need to correct for this?  How?